# CocoaAsyncSocket establish multiple connections

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, tcp, gcdasyncsocket

While trying to establish multiple TCP connections am getting "Attempting to connect while connected or accepting connections. Disconnect first" error,
Please suggest me how to establish 2 or more live TCP connections using CocoaAsyncSocket.

Comment: please complete stack overflow tour and learn how to ask question in better way.

Answer (score 1):

Create and use another GCDAsyncSocket instance if you are using GCDAsyncSocket library(if you are using NSStream also same process), you can differentiate TCP connection messages with connectedHost.